# How to get different between now and time in long in Android

Tags: java, android, datetime

G'day there!

I have task like show how many time was gone from message was created. For example, I send message 5 mins ago, I have time in long and I need to show message "5 mins ago".

I get current date from System.currentTimeMillis() and do sub of date when message was created, but how can I get message like "5 mins ago" I don't know.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that your long that represents the change in time is in milliseconds (assuming both the original message created timestamp and the current timestamp were both created via System.currentTimeMillis()).

You can then use simple math to convert milliseconds to minutes.
1,000 milliseconds  = 1 second, so 60,000 = 1 minute.

Where exactly were you getting stuck with this?

Comment: Could you be more tolerant? I feel only anger from your comment

Comment: I apologize if it came off that way. The "where were you getting stuck" line was there because I wasn't sure if that was where you were having problems, or if you were having problems with the String or actually displaying a message.

Comment: I thought that perhaps, Android framework has some utils for solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Convert the difference in the two times to minutes from milliseconds then concatenate the resulting time with a string " mins ago"

`long timeDifference = messageTime - currentTime;

  String message = (timeDifference/60000) + " mins ago";`

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
import java.util.Calendar;

public class DateDifferent{  
  public static void main(String[] args){
  long diff = yourMilliseconds - nowMilliseconds;
  long diffSeconds = diff / 1000;
  long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000);
  long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000);
  long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have this static method.

```
public static String getElapsedTime(Date oldDate) {
    long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - oldDate.getTime();
    long seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(duration);
    long days = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(duration);
    long hours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(duration);
    long minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(duration);

    if (days > 0) {
        return days + " days";
    }
    if (hours > 0) {
        return hours + " hrs";
    }
    if (minutes > 0) {
        return minutes + " minutes";
    }

    return seconds + " seconds";


}
```

Comment: instead of toDays => / 60 * 60 * 24, hours / 60 * 60, mins / 60. Thanks for answer